# Stored procedure to get default address among list of address for same user

Tags: stored-procedures

My use case is to store multiple addresses for a customer, and to be able to designate a single customer's address as the customer's default address.

I have three tables; `customer` (contains customer details), `address` (contains address details) and `customer_address` (maps customers to their addresses). In `customer_address` I have a field, `is_default`, that, allows the address to be designated as the default address for one customer (using `is_default`=1).

Is it possible to write a stored procedure that returns the default address for a given customer?

Comment: It would be helpful for you to include a schema of your database.

Comment: Just an observation - your field to point to a default address should be in the `customer` table.  This is because you can have one and only one default address.  Putting this field in your `customer_address` table makes it possible for multiple address records of a single customer to have `is_default` set true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you leave your database design as-is with the `is_default` field in the `customer_address` table, the query to return the default address might look something like below.  It would be trivial to turn this query into a stored procedure (the only parameter needed would be the ID of the customer for whom you wish to return their defulat address):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM customer c
  JOIN customer_address ca ON ca.customer_id = c.id
  JOIN address a ON a.id = ca.address_id
WHERE ca.is_default = 1;
```

If you change your database design to store the default address ID in the `customer` record, where perhaps it should be, the query is simplified:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM customer c
  JOIN address a ON a.id = c.default_address_id;
```

Of course, storing the default address in the customer record may make other aspects of your application more difficult, such as adding or removing addresses to/from a customer.